# Attempted import error: 'XhrIoPool' is not exported from '@firebase/webchannel-wrapper'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I installed firebase version 4.6.2. When I try to set up the firebase config I got this error. Can anyone help me with this.

Note: I set up the database config on the firebase website and everything fine.

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "key",
  authDomain: "project.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "project",
  storageBucket: "project.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1234",
  appId: "appid",
};

// Initialize the app
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Exporting the authentication(auth) and the database (firestore)
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

export const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export default firebase;
```

Comment: Which versions of firebase and firebase-admin are you using? As suggestion a recoment you not post your api Key and the other credentials in a public website with that information any one can use your database.